# Conversation Migration Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I have this model above, but I'm not sure how to handle the migration for this table. Basically, each 'conversation' could have multiple users, like a group chat, and then it also has many messages. Any idea of how I should create my migration?

```
class CreateConversations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :conversations do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My messages migration looks like this:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.references :sender
      t.references :conversation
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Does this look right?

Comment: Check the docs, it tells you how your migration should look for a HABTM relationship https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 1):

Your `conversations` and `messages` tables look fine, but your `Sender` (User?) model should have a `belongs_to` relation to `Conversation`. Add this in a `senders` migration:

`t.references :conversation`

EDIT: My bad, above solution assumes a one `Sender` to one `Conversation` relation, but a many to many relation seems more appropriate (a `Conversation` can have multiple `Sender`s, and a `Sender` can be in multiple `Conversation`s)

What you'd need in that case, is a `senders_conversations` table that maps this many-to-many relation. [Read up on ActiveRecord many-to-many here](https://www.sitepoint.com/master-many-to-many-associations-with-activerecord/)

`rails g migration CreateJoinTableAuthorsBooks authors books` from the link above is what you need (substitute authors and books with senders and conversations).

Comment: My user (sender) model has this:   has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations, dependent: :destroy

Would this work? 

This is really messy haha

Comment: I get this query for some reason when I run: User.first.conversations.to_sql

"SELECT \"conversations\".* FROM \"conversations\" INNER JOIN \"conversations_users\" ON \"conversations\".\"id\" = \"conversations_users\".\"conversation_id\" WHERE \"conversations_users\".\"user_id\" = 1"

Where is the "conversations_users" table even coming from??

Comment: @RyanGlen Rails knows that a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation needs such a table. Check your `db/schema.rb` file, you should be able to find the `conversations_users` table in there.